# Where is IIS log files folder location

Tags: logging, iis, logfile

I'm running an ASP.NET core application on IIS from Visual Studio 2019, and I can't find the log folder of IIS, could you please give me it's location?

If the application was running on a separated IIS, then I know that the log files should be found in C:\inetpub. However, in case I directly run the app from Visual Studio, as I understand - there's an instance of IIS within Visual studio - and it generates log files somewhere but not in C:\inetpub.

Comment: IIS Express does use a different default folder for log files `%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs`. You can use Jexus Manager to learn more, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager

Answer (score 0):

VS has a command for opening its logs folders. For the VS logs, you can use the `Devenv /log LogFile`.

More infor you can refer to this link: [Log (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms241272(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).